# Image View src not working in custom grid view adapter

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-cardview, baseadapter, android-gridview

I have a custom gridview adapter CoursesAdapter which is being used with cardview but due to some reasons image view src  does not work when set from arraylist. But when I assign image Id directly to imageView it works.

Any help is appreciated.

**Custom GridView Adapter**

```
    public class coursesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<Course> courseArrayList;

        //constructor

        public coursesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Course> courseArrayList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.courseArrayList = courseArrayList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return courseArrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Course getItem(int position) {
            return courseArrayList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final Course course=courseArrayList.get(position);
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.course_cardview,parent,false);
            final ImageView courseImage=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.course_image_imageView);

            final TextView courseTitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.course_title_textView);
   //Here if I use courseImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample_thumbnail); 
//image is shown            
      courseImage.setImageResource(courseArrayList.get(position).getImage());
            courseTitle.setText(courseArrayList.get(position).getName());

            return convertView;`enter code here`
        }
    }
```

As this adapter is for testing purpose I have filled array-list with same values.

**Array-list For Adapter**

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        courseArrayList.add(new Course("Maths","Arslan",R.drawable.sample_thumbnail));
```

**Course Class**

```
public class Course implements Parcelable{
    private String name; // course Name
    private String lecturer; // course lecturer
    private int image; //course Image

    //constructors

    public Course(String name, String lecturer, int image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lecturer = lecturer;
        this.image = image;
    }

    //Getters and Setters


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLecturer() {
        return lecturer;
    }

    public void setLecturer(String lecturer) {
        this.lecturer = lecturer;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    // Parcelable Overridden functions

    protected Course(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        lecturer = in.readString();
        image = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<Course> CREATOR = new Creator<Course>() {
        @Override
        public Course createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Course(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Course[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Course[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(lecturer);
        dest.writeInt(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: See my answer it will fix your problem. No need to use any 3rd party lib. You can accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line :

```
courseImage.setImageResource(courseArrayList.get(position).getImage());
```

To :

```
courseImage.setImageResource(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,courseArrayList.get(position).getImage()));
```

Comment: Hi @Koustuv Ganguly using your code I'm getting error  setImageSource(Int) in ImageView can not be applied to android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

Comment: please post the error or logcat

Comment: I think you mistook setImageResourse with setImageDrawable. I tried this too but still its not working.

Comment: Oops..! But what do you mean by not working?

Comment: Well by not working I mean I get a blank(white) image view without any image

Comment: try with setBackGround property

Comment: It seams somehow image got corrupted. I have tried my own code with different image in arrayList and its working fine. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

add this library

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

and add this in your adapter

```
Picasso.get().load(courseArrayList.get(position).getImage()).into(imageView1);
```

let me know if this work or not

Comment: Hi @pratik vekariya I would prefer solution without any Libraries. Still Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

add this library

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
```

and your code for view image

```
Glide.with(context).load(courseArrsylist.get(position).getImage())
            .override(100, 100)// here your can use the size of image
            .into(courseImage);
```